# Error 500 in JsonObjectRequest in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I'm struggling with error 500 during sending a JSON Object to my Server. I'm using POST method because I need to save user in the database. I suppose something is wrong in my request cause the output doesn't print (in onResponse method). On the server side, the data is not printed too but there is no exception handled, no errors - everything going okay but data is still not there!

Android register method:

```
public class RegisterIndividualActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_individual);
        setListeners();
    }

    private void setListeners() {
        final EditText loginField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginField);
        final EditText passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordField);

        Button registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerButton);

        registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                register(
                        loginField.getText(),
                        passwordField.getText(),
                );
            }
        });
    }

    private void register(final Editable login,
                          final Editable password){
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Creating new acc...");
        progressDialog.show();

        RequestQueue queueAcc = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String urlAcc = getResources().getString(R.string.server_address)+"android/user/register?login="
                + login.toString() + "&password=" + password.toString();


        JSONObject newUser = new JSONObject();
        try {
            newUser.put("login", login.toString());
            newUser.put("password", password.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("USER TO SAVE: " + newUser.toString());
        JsonObjectRequest urlAccStringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, urlAcc, newUser, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        System.out.println("Good morning " + login.toString()); //doesnt print

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { //i got this error
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(RegisterIndividualActivity.this, "Connection error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        queueAcc.add(urlAccStringRequest);

        queueAcc.start();
    }
}
```

The controller on the server side (this is in proper class with @Controller adnotation and needed mapping which is android/user):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void register(
        @RequestParam("login") String login,
        @RequestParam("password") String password,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model
){
    System.out.println("\nIn Register method..");
    UserModel uM = new UserModel();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    uM.setAccountType("Client");
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    try {
        System.out.println("\nTrying to save..");
        JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) parser.parse(request.getReader());
        System.out.println(jsonObject.get("login").toString()); //event this doesnt print
        uM.setLogin(jsonObject.get("login").toString());
        uM.setPassword(jsonObject.get("password").toString());
        System.out.println(uM.toString()); //doesnt print
        userDAO.save(uM);
    } catch (IOException e) { // doesnt throw exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    System.out.println(uM.toString()); // doesnt print

}
```

**@EDIT** Added server log:

```
19-Jun-2017 19:42:22.757 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-mvc] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonObject cannot be cast to javax.json.JsonObject] with root cause
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonObject cannot be cast to javax.json.JsonObject
    at com.mvc.controller.AndroidUserController.register(AndroidUserController.java:145)
    at com.mvc.controller.AndroidUserController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$448b2d05.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.mvc.controller.AndroidUserController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$47d3305.register(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**@EDIT 2**

This is server log after changing try-catch block to this:

```
 try {
        System.out.println("\nTrying to save..");
        JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) parser.parse(request.getReader());
        System.out.println(jsonObject.get("login").toString()); //event this doesnt print

    } catch (IOException e) { // doesnt throw exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Server log:

```
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**@EDIT 3!!!!**

I figured out that this line is cousing the errors showed in the second server log:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) parser.parse(request.getReader());
```

What's wrong with that?

**@EDIT 4**

This is my current code for reading the json:

```
try {
            System.out.println("\nTrying to save...");
            InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
            JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(inputStream); //this is were error is 
            reader.close();
//            JsonObject jsonObject = reader.readObject();
//            reader.close();
//            System.out.println(jsonObject.get("login").toString()); 
////            uM.setLogin(jsonObject.get("login").toString());
//            uM.setPassword(jsonObject.get("password").toString());
//            System.out.println(uM.toString()); 
//            userDAO.save(uM);
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And this is current server log:

```
    19-Jun-2017 21:36:34.490 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
19-Jun-2017 21:36:34.617 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
19-Jun-2017 21:36:46.631 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring-mvc'
19-Jun-2017 21:36:57.007 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-mvc] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.json.JsonException: Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found] with root cause
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at javax.json.spi.JsonProvider.provider(JsonProvider.java:94)
    at javax.json.Json.createReader(Json.java:220)
    at com.mvc.controller.AndroidUserController.register(AndroidUserController.java:146)
    at com.mvc.controller.AndroidUserController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$448b2d05.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.mvc.controller.AndroidUserController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f920f9fc_2.register(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

`com.google.gson.JsonObject cannot be cast to javax.json.JsonObject`

You seem to have imported the wrong JsonObject class

If you are using Gson, this is not [**how to parse JSON** with it](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#object-examples)

```
JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) parser.parse(request.getReader());
```

Comment: No, thats not the error, see the second Edit. The imports are ok , I suppose the core problem is in the second log

Comment: anyway, thats strange couse that error occured in the second line (password). With the login everything went OK

Comment: Are you sure that isn't the problem? `AndroidUserController.register(AndroidUserController.java:145)`... If you are using Gson, you would not be using a `JsonParser` object, you would be using a `new Gson()` object

Comment: I get rid of that error, I'm using Json only. The first log is not actual anymore

Comment: Okay, you can update your question with the latest logs, then?

Comment: "Using JSON only" isn't a thing. You were always using JSON. Which library now? `javax.json`

Comment: Yes, im using javax.json

Comment: Okay, now it looks like you have messed up the classpath. I think you were fine with having Gson, but you were not using it correctly.